# Union of a sequence of path connected sets being path connected

Tags: general-topology

Theorem:
Let ${A_n}$ be a sequence of path connected subsets of a space $X$ such that for each integer $n\ge 1$, $A_n$ has at least one point in common with one the preceding sets $A_1, ..., A_{n-1}$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is path connected.

I am trying to prove this theorem however, I'm having trouble constructing a proof because I don't know how to deal with the condition that $A_n$ has at least one point in common with one the preceding sets $A_1, ..., A_{n-1}$. How can I prove this theorem?

Comment: Hint: Use induction to prove that $\cup_{n=1}^N A_n$ is path connected for each $N$.

Comment: Is $\{S*[0,1]\}$ where $S= \{1/n : n \in N\}$ path connected? We can write this to be $ \cup_N \{1/n*[0,1]\}$ union of path connected sets, but does that mean $\{S*[0,1]\}$ is path connected?

Comment: I think this isn't path connected since $S$ is discrete.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this theorem?  Hatcher?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x, y \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Then by definition, $x\in A_n$ and $y\in A_m$ for some $m, n$. So it suffices to show that

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^K A_n$$

is path connected for all $K$, given the condition. We can do induction on $K$. So it suffices to show that if $A_1, A_2 \subset X$ are two path connected subset in $X$ with $A_1\cap A_2 \neq \emptyset$, then $A_1\cup A_2$ is also path connected. Is that easier now?

Comment: Why does $x, y \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \Rightarrow x\in A_n$ and $y\in A_m$ for some $m, n$ ? If I take $X = \Bbb R, A_n = [ \frac{1}{n}, 1], \ n\geq 1$, then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = [0, 1]$ and $0 \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = [0, 1]$ but $0 \notin A_n \ \forall n$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Note that $\bigcup_{n} A_n = (0,1]$ in your example. Note that $x\in \bigcup_n A_n$ implies $x\in A_n$ follows from definition of $\bigcup_n A_n$ @Desura

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, my mistake. I was thinking of an arbitrary union as a limit, which is completely wrong. I should stick to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a space is path connected is to show that if $x,y$ are two points in that space, there is a path from $x$ to $y$.

If $x,y\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ then for some index $j$ we have $x\in A_j$ and for some index $k$ we have $y\in A_k$.

The set $A_j$ has a point $x_\ell$ in common with $A_\ell$ for some $\ell<j$, and $A_k$ has a point $x_m$ in common with $A_m$ for some $m<k$.  So there's a path from $x$ to $x_\ell$ and there's a path from $y$ to $y_m$.  Then $A_\ell$ has a point in common with some point in some subset with a smaller index than $\ell$ and that one has a point in common with some subset with a still smaller index, and so on.  EXCEPT, that we cannot go on forever getting smaller numbers in the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  So eventually we'll have a path from $x$ to some point in $A_1$.  And similarly a path from $y$ to some point in $A_1$.  And then we can draw a path connecting those two points in $A_1$ (Since $A_1$ is path connected).  Hence a path from $x$ to $y$.

(Of course, it's possible that we'll get a path from $x$ to $y$ without going as far as $A_1$, but if all else fails, that does it.)